Alternatives to ArrayList<Double> for primitive types in Java for numerical computation
My question is: What are the best practices to avoid the mentioned overhead? I don't understand why my question was closed with the reason: 'This question needs to be more focused.'
I am currently working on numerical computations in a specific research domain and have inherited a Java package implemented long time ago by my team. My task now is to optimize its performance. The package makes extensive use of ArrayList<Double>. As far as I know, Java, at least up to version 9 which I am using, does not support ArrayList of primitive types due to type erasure in Java generics.
There are a few issues with this:

Storage overhead: Double is a wrapper class for double. Since Double is an object, it includes an object header, which takes up 8 bytes. Therefore, each Double object takes up 16 bytes of memory.

Non-contiguous memory: ArrayList internally uses an array to store Double objects, i.e., Double[] data. This array holds references to Double instances. These instances are not stored contiguously in the heap. For example, if Double[] data = {1.0, 2.0}, the references in data are contiguous, but the actual Double objects that these references point to are not. This leads to poor locality and frequent cache misses due to the need to dereference these pointers.

Unboxing and autoboxing: There is additional overhead due to unboxing and autoboxing when performing comparisons and calculations with Double.


My questions are:
What are the best practices to avoid the mentioned overhead? I welcome any answers regarding the questions below.

Are there any new features in the latest versions of Java that allow the use of ArrayList with primitive types?

Are there any experimental features, frameworks, or libraries that support this?

If not, would it be feasible to to create a personal DoubleArrayList by replacing all Object in the ArrayList source code by primitive double? What would be the potential pitfalls of this approach?


PS:

We are on a very tight schedule and do not have the time to rewrite the entire package in C++, where vector<double> is available.

In our use case, the container will change size during computation, and we don't know the size beforehand. Therefore, we must use a resizable array (such as ArrayList) instead of double[].



You could consider using a 3rd-party collections library; e.g. the old GNU Trove library.  But note that this libraries and others like it are necessarily incompatible with java.util.List.

You could consider using a 3rd-party collections library; e.g. the old GNU Trove library.  But note that this library and others like it are necessarily incompatible with java.util.List.  (Google for "java high performance collections", and research the alternatives for yourself.)

Tip: Avoid the terms "best practice" and "best way" on Stack Overflow. Such terms often receive close-votes in a knee-jerk fashion without actually reading the Question, unfortunately.

Project Valhalla

Are there any new features in the latest versions of Java that allow the use of ArrayList with primitive types?

Work is underway that may blur the two type systems in Java, primitives versus objects. See Project Valhalla.

Are there any experimental features

The Project Valhalla work has not yet released any features to meet your needs. While under active development now, you will not soon benefit from this work.
Eclipse Collections

libraries that support this?

The Eclipse Collections library offers primitives collections. This includes interfaces:

DoubleList
ImmutableDoubleList
MutableDoubleList

… with these implementations:

DoubleArrayList
SynchronizedDoubleList
UnmodifiableDoubleList

Example:
MutableDoubleList doubleList = DoubleLists.mutable.of( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 );

You should see a dramatic reduction in memory usage. For example, see this chart of memory saved with the primitive-based IntArrayList in Eclipse Foundation rather than the ArrayList<Integer> bundled with Java.

See the manual for more info.

would it be feasible to to create a personal DoubleArrayList

Yes, you could, as discussed in Answer by Bohemian.
But I would first examine the Eclipse Collections classes before any consideration of writing my own.
Eclipse Collections is open-source. So you can verify the implementation details yourself.

do not have the time to rewrite the entire package in C++, where vector is available.

I would expect that massaging the Java code to take advantage of Eclipse Collections classes would be much easier, quicker, and less error-prone than a total re-write in another language.
Java versions

version 9 which I am using,

Know that Java 9 is end-of-life.
I strongly recommend moving to an LTS version of Java: 8, 11, 17, 21, and likely 25.
See Java Version History at Wikipedia.

Use double[].
The "free" resizing of ArrayList is just a convenience - when more space is needed, the internal backing array is replaced by one twice as large and the elements copied across using an old school loop.
It's a trivial implementation to code yourself.
Create a class with a double[] field and basically copy what you need from ArrayList but add a getter method for the array and use that for your computations.
If you can get away with it, use float[] instead as operations on float will be roughly twice as fast as for double.

Thanks. It's equivalent to writing a wrapper class for double[], which functions similarly to an ArrayList of doubles.

Is the float vs double performance largely due to the memory footprint (and thus caching, etc)? I would have thought that on modern hardware, they would both be handled by the same hardware under the hood (and specifically, that they'd both be widened to the CPU/FPU's precision, which is higher than either's).

@yshavit memory and processor; on a 32-bit CPU, calculations take twice the cycles. 64-bit machines no difference. Similarly for memory. You're probably correct though - most machines are 64-bit architecture now.

@Bohemian Ah, okay, that makes sense -- thanks! I was assuming 64-bit (especially given that OP's team clearly has performance in mind, so I'm assuming they're using modern CPUs, and probably mid- to high-end at that), and didn't know if even in that world there's a difference between floats and doubles.

Insofar as an algorithm can be vectorized into SIMD instructions float[] array processing could theoretically be up to twice as fast on a 64-bit CPU. Unfortunately the opposite is quite often the case in practice as the JVM Hotspot compiler does much better SIMD optimizations for double[] arrays than for float[].
